# Move back to running instance of browser

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm working on Robot Framework (Selenium2Library). In my Test case, I've to perform some functionality on browser instance ( Web application) and some functionality on a desktop application (Here I'm using UFT). I'm executing VBS script to execute UFT (Automation Tool). I'm doing this successfully and handling the flow from Browser to the desktop application. Once the task of the desktop application is ended, I should move back to the current instance of Browser (Focus on Web application). I tried Select Window keyword. But no luck. Is there any way to move back to instance of Browser? 
Note: browser instance is executing my test case successfully in background. I want it on the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

inject javascript alert and handle it, then browser will be active on desktop.

something like this

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("alert('OK')")
```

and handle it.